# how can i use a PASSWORD protected ACCESS database as a backend of my Vb.net project....?

Tags: vb.net, connection, acc

I has a Access  database  ...that is password protected....
i am connecting in this manner given as follow .......(Without password protection)

cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\My Documents\db2.mdb")

```
    cn.Open()
```

///codes.......

```
    cn.close()
```

how can i edit that can use for access those password protected Access database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connectionstrings.com is always very helpful when trying to work out what your connection string should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the username and password in the connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password=secret;User ID=Admin;Data Source=D:\My Documents\db2.mdb
```